# In meteor, how can I get a handle on the underlying sockjs server?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'd like to access the sockjs api that meteor leverages to do its real-time updating. Meteor emits something like `http://localhost:3000/sockjs/348/zfjta7hy/xhr` and I'd like to leverage the sockjs api in order to circumvent the pub/sub stuff in meteor with something like this:

```
var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:3000/sockjs/dynamically_created_by_meteor');
```

And then simply use `sock` to do some collaborative work that's outside the scope of meteor's real-time updating. I haven't dug through the code enough yet to see this, but am wondering if anyone has an idea on how I can get a sockjs url handle in meteor? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a similar question here, the solution isn't perfect but it works: [Publish arbitrary data and automatically update HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148287/publish-arbitrary-data-and-automatically-update-html/12189475#12189475)

Answer (score 0):

After digging through firebug and examining the `Meteor` object, I found this, which provides the `SockJS` url as of Meteor 0.3.9

```
Meteor.default_connection.stream.socket._transport.poll.recv_url
```

Comment: Ultimately, I intend on building a sockjs client using the above URL and issue `send` commands to broadcast custom events, but the `Meteor.default_connection.stream` object has a `send` command as well, though I'm not sure yet whether it's more appropriate to leverage that directly or build my own sockjs object with the URL.