# How to I use Meteor when acting on a javascript object outside the scope of the reactive templating engine?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have some javascript objects that I'd like to collaboratively manipulate, but am having a hard time understanding the best way to achieve this in `Meteor`. These objects are NOT bound to specific collections, but rather live in-memory alongside the Templates that serve GUIs that are bound to collections.

I figured two things:

(1) Perhaps I should circumvent Meteor's native pub/sub stuff for this and simply leverage the existing `SockJS` infrastructure inside `Meteor`. I was [able to get the `SockJS` URL from `Meteor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024357/in-meteor-how-can-i-get-a-handle-on-the-underlying-sockjs-server/12024426#12024426), but haven't successfully made a `SockJS` call yet. (I can provide more detail if need be)

(2) Or maybe leverage the existing pub/sub options in `Meteor` and use a Template as a shim to listen for updating. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109788/callback-after-the-dom-was-updated-in-meteor-js) for that, but so far, haven't been able to iron out the kinks. Perhaps I should use a collection as a shim as well?

Again, these are NOT bound to collections, and I'd suspect vanilla `SockJS` or `socket.io` to be fairly straightforward on how to broadcast the changes. So, I'm struggling on how to incorporate collaboration in a `Meteor` app that doesn't originate with a collection being updated. I want to pursue one of the above, but would like to know which approach seems most feasible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you say 'are not bound to collections' what does that mean exactly? You don't want to persist the data?

Comment: It's mostly navigational -- users will be moving around in a given app and the data (navigation coordinates, etc) doesn't need persistence as it's a one-off experience. But I think there are number of scenarios outside navigation that warrant a means of collaborative manipulation without needing to be bound to a specific collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the new `constant` block helper that was released with Meteor 0.4.0 to keep my out-of-Meteor-scope javascript objects from being manipulated by `Meteor`:

http://meteor.com/blog/2012/08/31/introducing-spark-a-new-live-page-update-engine

This lets me update these objects via a different means than `Meteor`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two scenarios:

1. Things that need to be collaborated on I think should be persisted in a collection. However if there is a large amount of such data that is very transient and it really doesn't make sense to use a collection, it is theoretically possible to wire up a collection which uses minimongo (in memory mongo) on the server side rather than the real mongo driver.

   The devs have indicated that it probably can be done, but AFAIK no one has actually gone ahead and tried it.
2. Things that don't need to be collaborated on should just be stored in the `Session` client side I think.