# Publish arbitrary data and automatically update HTML

Tags: meteor

How do I publish arbitrary data? This is what I want to accomplis, giving the following template:

```
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>{{greeting}} World!</h1>
</template>
```

I would like to dynamically update `greeting` on set intervals, using `Meteor.setInterval`. All examples in the documentation seems to be about `Collections` though.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Meteor Session variable as a reactive data source so the template automatically re-renders (http://docs.meteor.com/#session_set). Try this:-

```
if (Meteor.is_client) {

  // Use 'greeting' Session variable as a reactive data source
  Session.set('greeting', 0);

  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to test: " + Session.get('greeting');
  };

  Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    Session.set('greeting', Session.get('greeting') + 1);
  }, 1000);
}

if (Meteor.is_server) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

**Updated:** To show hooking into `streams` package. Example works but use at your own peril

```
if (Meteor.is_client) {
  // Use client from stream package
  sc = new Meteor._Stream('/sockjs');
  sc.on('message', function(payload) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(payload);

    // Set session variable so template reacts
    Session.set('greeting', JSON.stringify(msg.data));
  });

  // Use 'greeting' Session variable as a reactive data source
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return Session.get('greeting');
  };
}

if (Meteor.is_server) {
  // Use server from stream package
  ss = new Meteor._StreamServer();

  // register handler for socket connection
  ss.register(function (socket) {
    var data = {socket: socket.id, connected: new Date()}
    var msg = {msg: 'data', data: data};

    // Send message to all sockets
    _.each(ss.all_sockets(), function(socket) {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like this to be synced between clients. Updated at the same time with the same message.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean. The `Meteor.Publish(..)` and `Meteor.Subscribe(..)` functions are solely for `Collections` which is why you couldn't find anything in the docs. You could either use a `Collection` to sync data between client and server although I agree that seems quite clunky if you only want to post an arbitrary message to clients.

Another 'hack' you could try is hooking into the underlying `SockJS` library or the `streams` package. The `streams` approach is going to be simpler but also riskier as the methods havent been exposed to us and their implementation is liable to change.

Comment: I've added a basic example of illustrating how to hack into the `streams` package included with `Meteor`. It shows the connection time of the latest socket opened with the server. If another client connects all clients are updated with the latest socket time.

Comment: If you still want to push to the clients at intervals using `Meteor.setInterval` you could do so by just iterating over `all_sockets()` within a function.

Answer (score 1):

Hi checkout this new [Streams Package](http://meteorhacks.com/introducing-meteor-streams.html). You can simply use it for your usecase

```
sc = new Meteor.Stream('hello');

if(Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    sc.emit('a_random_message', 'Random Message: ' + Random.id());
  }, 2000);

  Meteor.permissions.read(function() { return true });
}

if(Meteor.isClient) {
  sc.on('a_random_message', function(message) {
    Session.set('a_random_message', message);
  });

  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return Session.get('a_random_message');   
  };
}
```

Comment: This is useful. Is there any way to integrate this into iron-router - i.e., have a waitOn() method wait on a Meteor Stream?

Comment: Not yet. Streams API is bit awkward. Looking for some new ways to implement with Reactive Data Sources.
Will release soon(not so) with the new DDPPlus package I'm working on.