# Can I publish only Collections object in meteor?

Tags: collections, meteor, publish-subscribe

On the introducing article of DDP, I read that anything can be published, but I've read somewhere ( for example in this Stackoverflow comment [Publish arbitrary data and automatically update HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148287/publish-arbitrary-data-and-automatically-update-html#comment16364053_12189475) ) that only Collections can be published.

So where is the truth? If we can publish other things than Collections, I would liek to see an example as I can't find one so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish

> Publish functions can return a Collection.Cursor, in which case Meteor will publish that cursor's documents. You can also return an array of Collection.Cursors, in which case Meteor will publish all of the cursors.

So at the moment you can only return a Collection via a cursor (result of a `Collection.find()`).

To return other data you need to hack into the sockjs stream (the socket library meteor uses to communicate to the server). Be aware this does not guarantee compatibility with future versions of meteor. Sockjs is the library used for meteor to communicate between the server (the wire)

**from [Publish arbitrary data and automatically update HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148287/publish-arbitrary-data-and-automatically-update-html#comment16364053_12189475)***

**client side js**

```
sc = new Meteor._Stream('/sockjs');   
sc.on('message', function(payload) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(payload);
    Session.set('a_random_message', JSON.stringify(msg.data));   
});

Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return Session.get('a_random_message');   
};
```

**server side js**

```
ss = new Meteor._StreamServer();

ss.register(function (socket) {
    var data = {socket: socket.id, connected: new Date()}
    var msg = {msg: 'data', data: data};

     // Send message to all sockets (which will be set in the Session a_random_message of the client
     _.each(ss.all_sockets(), function(socket) {
         socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
     });   
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Am right to say that another hack would be to create a Collection for any variable/object I want to publish?

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at [Meteor Streams](http://meteorhacks.com/introducing-meteor-streams.html) too. See below.

> assume you have added meteor streams via atmosphere - `mrt add streams`

```
sc = new Meteor.Stream('hello');

if(Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    sc.emit('a_random_message', 'Random Message: ' + Random.id());
  }, 2000);

  Meteor.permissions.read(function() { return true });
}

if(Meteor.isClient) {
  sc.on('a_random_message', function(message) {
    Session.set('a_random_message', message);
  });

  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return Session.get('a_random_message');   
  };
}
```